# Access to methods in xhtml file - JSF in Netbeans

Tags: jsf, netbeans

In IDE's like IntelliJ IDEA you can access to the bean method with CTRL + B or CTRL + click, in that case i the method is for example...

```
<p:commandButton ....  actionListener="#{helloPageJSFBean.findAction}" />
```

But in netbeans i only can access to it in this way

```
<p:commandButton ....  actionListener="#{helloPageJSFBean.findAction(actionEvent)}" />
```

The problem with it is the jsf page does not working when i press the botton but in the first way it works

How i can configure Netbeans for can access at the specific method line ? Thanks.

Aditional information: Im using JSF 2.1 and my method is

```
@Transactional
public void findAction(ActionEvent actionEvent) {

    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    UIViewRoot root = context.getViewRoot();

    resetDataTable(root);

    setCursorTableNull();
    onFind(actionEvent);

    //return SAME_PAGE;
}
```

Comment: When you code like in the second way, how are you filling the `actionEvent` parameter in your JSF code?

Comment: I dont work with de second way its only to show you that in that way, Netbeans can access the method but i work in the first way.

Comment: What version of NetBeans are you using?

Comment: Im using the 7.2 version

Comment: This "error" is fixed in the 7.3 Version